# Display "open with other application" as a sub-menu

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-3, nautilus

I am almost certain in an older version of Gnome 3, the context menu when right clicking on a file would contain an *open with sub-menu*. This menu is very useful for HTML files where sometimes I want to open these files in the browser, sometimes in a text editor.

The current solution (shown below) which requires selecting the application for the file using an *open with* dialog is much slower. Is there a way to revert to the older more efficient behaviour?

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is a "feature" introduced in a recent version of GNOME. https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=777132

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative using **nautilus actions** all you have to do is to download it using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-actions
```

1. Search for "nautilus-actions" and click Nautilus-Actions Configuration.
2. Click the add icon.
3. from the **actions** tab write your context label like 'Open with firefox'
4. Choose an appropriate icon.
5. Go to **command** tab and browse or write your browser path like **/usr/bin/firefox**
6. Save and go to your file right-click and you'll notice the **Open With Firefox** action.

NOTE: you may have to logout to see the changes.

Comment: Excellent, thank you Mohammad, this example worked for me using Filemanager ACtions which is the new version of Nautilus actions apparently. 

However, it only shows these actions in a submenu called "Filemanager Actions actions". Is there a way to have it in the root of the context menu? And is it possible for me to remove unwanted context menu actions that are there by default?

Comment: nvm I found it! It's in the preferences. Thank you for such an easy to follow tutorial! Also do you know where I can find documentation on the syntax for passing various kinds of parameters etc?

Comment: Thank you David. But what do you mean by the parameters ? 
Do you mean the paths ??

Comment: I was trying to see what the built in path variables like %b and %f were. I wasn't sure what all they were.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure of what do you want to achieve through such variables and I am not aware of any. But a command that may help you to find out an application's path is the type command. Example: `type -p firefox`

Answer (score 0):

You just have to do it for the first time then nautilus will save your choice and add an open with to the menu.

Comment: This isn't possible. If I go to the open with tab from the properties dialog, I can change the default application but I can not add an application. There is an add button that might be intended to do this, but it is disabled.

Comment: Do you have "Other Applications" list ?

Comment: I had a look, all the apps are already in the "Other Applications" list, although this list is only accessible via clicking on "Open With Other Application" and then selecting the application from the new dialog. I want to select this directly from the menu like before.

Comment: What is your exact version ?
Try to upgrade **sudo apt-get upgrade nautilus** anyway.

Comment: `nautilus --version` gives me: GNOME nautilus 3.20.4, the add button on the open with dialog is still always disabled

Comment: try to run **nautilus -c** to perform a quick set of self-check tests.
If it doesn't work you can simply use **nautilus-actions** 
[nautilus-actions](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/getdeb_apps/precise/apps/getdeb/nautilus-actions)
or do it manually: [add-to-list](https://ubuntugenius.wordpress.com/2012/06/18/ubuntu-fix-add-program-to-list-of-applications-in-open-with-when-right-clicking-files-in-nautilus/)

Comment: `nautilus -c` seems to just hang indefinitely. If you can provide a more comprehensive second answer based on nautilus actions, I will accept this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

forget nautilus-actions, try nautilus-python, you can find examples inside usr/share/doc/python-nautilus/examples/.

or , you can try my script:
https://github.com/dwSun/utils/blob/master/Linux/open-terminator.py